# Adding an external link to product grid list pages for woocommerce

Tags: theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to add an extra button or link to the product list page

I have been looking for a solution but couldn't get one

Can someone help me out with the solution and the target file
[image: This what I want to acheive]

Answer (score 1):

A possible hook to position a button in that point is *woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item*:

```
add_action("woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item","Stack_308575_add_button",99);

function Stack_308575_add_button(){
  global $product;
  echo "<button onclick=\"alert(".wc_get_product($product)->id.")\">Click</button>";
}
```

If you need dynamic links you can get the global $product object and retrieve data from there